# How to download entire Googlesamples repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch

I've been trying to download the repo at: [Google Samples at GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples)
using curl but I failed in doing so. How do I clone the entire organization repository on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The page you point to is not **a** repository, it's a (rather big) **collection** of repositories. You cannot clone them at once, you have to choose one or two you really need and clone them with command

```
git clone $URL
```

Put the proper URL. For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python
```

Comment: I'm trying to download the entire collection at once

Comment: There is no way. And certainly not with an http mirroring tool as the site is not just a web site.